# How to extract django objects having maximal value?

Tags: python, mysql, django, python-2.7

Supposing I have a django model:

```
class Score(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    value = models.IntegerField()
    status = models.BooleanField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"{}: {} {}".format(self.name, self.value, self.status)
```

And the table `score` looks line this:

```
id | name  | value | status
---+-------+-------+-------
1  | john  | 15    | 0
2  | ivan  | 21    | 0
3  | david | 14    | 1
4  | john  | 11    | 1
5  | john  | 25    | 0
6  | david | 8     | 1
```

I want to extract the objects with maximal `value` for each name given as a list of names. For example:

```
names = ['john', 'david', 'paul']

dct = process(names) # How to implement this function???

for name, obj in dct.items():
    print name, obj
```

should print:

```
john john: 25 False
david david: 14 True
paul None
```

The performance matters. I am supposed to process around 10k names having around 1k records for each name in `score`. What is the best way to do it with django? Does it make a sense to use django ORM in this task?

I use MySQL database.

Thanks for advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
def process(names):
    # Finding max scores
    result = Score.objects.filter(name__in=names).\
        values('name').annotate(Max('value'))

    value_max_items = set(
        row['value__max']
        for row in result
    )

    # Query for objects having max scores
    result = Score.objects.filter(value__in=value_max_items)

    # Creating dct
    dct = {}
    for obj in result:
        if obj.name not in dct or obj.value > dct[obj.name].value:
            dct[obj.name] = obj

    # If some names missed, set None for them
    for name in names:
        if name not in dct:
            dct[name] = None

    return dct
```